# How to move the x-axis labels on a datetime scale further from the edges?

Tags: anychart

I have this chart: https://playground.anychart.com/D7okDBpO/2

I would like the plot and x-axis labels to have some padding from the left and right edges (one of the reasons is that the last x-label is not even fully visible right now), similarly to how a chart with ordinal scale is rendered. For the plot I managed to do this with:

```
series.left(30);
series.right(30);
```

But I can't find a solution for the x labels. What I've tried:

```
// This doesn't work because it moves both first and last label
chart.xAxis().labels().offsetX(-30);

// This doesn't work because it moves all the labels, even the ones in the middle
chart.xAxis().labels().padding().left(50);
```

Comment: The problem with the last x-label rendering outside of the chart happens even with ordinal scale and many data points: https://playground.anychart.com/AIHDJhfn/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you looking for this setting:

```
chart.left(20);
chart.right(20);
```

https://playground.anychart.com/miB1VAbq ?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. This helps with the x labels beeing outside of the chart, but the fix with 'series.left() and series.right()' isn't actually working because then the points aren't aligned with the x labels and x grid.

Comment: No, don't use series.left() and series.right(), it's a bad practice. Here you'll need to set the x-scale minimumGap() and maximumGap(). Please pay attention to the lines 20-23 in this sample: https://playground.anychart.com/lhLPfEp3.

Learn more about these methods in the API: https://api.anychart.com/anychart.scales.DateTime#minimumGap
https://api.anychart.com/anychart.scales.DateTime#maximumGap